# How to prove set theory problems

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'm in discrete math and am not understanding how to prove the set theory problems. I can follow along when I see the answers, but there's one part I'm having a hard time coming up with on my own.

In a problem like this:

Prove that if $X\subseteq Y$ then $X\cap Z\subseteq Y\cap Z$ for all sets $X$, $Y$, and $Z.$

The proofs always start out with "let $x$ be an element of (insert some set here)
(for this problem its let x be an element of $X∩Z.$

How do we know what to let $X$ be an element of in these types of problem? Is there a general concept to follow? Sometimes there are multiple parts to the conclusion so how do you know what to let $X$ be an element of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Venn diagram might help

[image]

If you are uncertain, or want to be really bullet proof, you can go through all of the cases.  $x\in X$ and $Y$... $x\in Y$ but not in $X,$ etc. and enumerate all of the cases.  And, as you get more experience you will see that some are irrelevant and don't need to be discussed.

Suppose the proposition is not true.  Then there is an element of $x\in X\cap Z$ that is not in $Y\cap Z.$  But that would imply that there is an $x\in X$ that is not in $Y$ which is in contradiction to the statement that $X$ is a subset of $Y.$

Comment: but how do I even know what to start with? how should I even know to let x be an element of X∩Z? My teacher never explains it she just does it

Comment: why are we even allowed to let x be an element of that? just because x is in x and y doesn't mean we can allow it to be in the intersect of x and z

Comment: As I said, you can enumerate all of the cases... Draw a Venn diagram.  Certainly if $X\cap Z$ is not empty, we can choose an element from it, (and if the set is empty the proposition is true because the empty set is trivially a subset).  And every element we choose will be an element of $X$ and an element of $Z.$  And every element of $X$ is also an element of $Y$  so it will also be an element of $Y\cap Z$

Comment: Ah I see. I just drew the Venn diagram myself and it made quite a bit more sense. So you choose x to be an element of x intersects z because it is the smallest grouping that's also apart of y, which gives you a lot of flexibility with your proof... or at least thats how I'm seeing it. is that true - am I thinking of that right?

Comment: That is the idea.  The direct way is to show that what applies for the most restricted zone must apply to the other zones.  Sometimes it is easier to talk about what cannot be true and eliminate.

Comment: That makes much more sense now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

It's based on definition of subset: we say, that $A \subset B$ if $\forall x(x\in A \Rightarrow x \in B)$.

Now in your case we want to prove that from $X \subset Y$ we obtain $X\cap Z \subset  Y\cap Z$, so we assume, that $\forall x(x\in X \Rightarrow x \in Y)$   is true.

Then let's take  $$(x \in X\cap Z) \Rightarrow (x \in X \land x \in Z) \Rightarrow (x \in Y \land x \in Z) \Rightarrow (x \in Y\cap Z)$$

Comment: but how do I even know what to start with? how should I even know to let x be an element of X∩Z? why are we even allowed to let x be an element of that? just because x is in x and y doesn't mean we can allow it to be in the intersect of x and z

Comment: @Isabelle Kreienbrink. We start with definitions, right? We look what definition demand and then try to check it. In this example I brought definition of subset in my answer - look at it, please. Exactly from there we start: we want that $\forall x$ satisfies some condition. So we take $\forall x$. Now, **IF** it is in $A$, **THEN** we need to show, that this $x$ is also in $B$. This is understandable? If yes, I'll continue, if no, write, please, in which you have doubt.